# Django/Bootstrap password input field doesn't work on mobile

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have [a Django and Bootstrap signup form](https://stagingpy.zana.io/accounts/signup-or-login) that's working fine on desktop. On mobile, I can't do anything with the password field. The cursor and keyboard never appear when I tap on the signup password fields (all the other fields are fine, including the password field for the login form on the same page).

This is how the HTML is being rendered via Django's "{{ form|bootstrap }}":

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label  " for="id_password1">Password</label>
    <div class=" ">
        <input class=" form-control" id="id_password1" name="password1" placeholder="Password" type="password" />            
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label  " for="id_password2">Password (again)</label>
    <div class=" ">
        <input class=" form-control" id="id_password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The login password field that does work renders like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label  " for="id_password">Password</label>
    <div class=" ">
        <input class=" form-control" id="id_password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />   
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what the signup form with the failing password fields looks like:

[image]

Any ideas about what's going on and how I can fix it?

UPDATE: using just "{{ form }}" instead of "{{ form|bootstrap }}", the password fields work, so it seems like it's a Bootstrap problem. I'd prefer to have the Bootstrap styles applied, so I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Why are you using col 6 in mobile? Try col-xs-12 for both password fields in mobile.

Comment: The problem is the "signup" button that is blocking the user action on password field. Add a margin top on the signup button to fix your issue.

Comment: karthikr, thanks. For some reason the signup-container, vertical-line-container, and login-container are overlapping. How can I get them to follow each other?

Comment: I dont see the elements rendered in the format you show as a part of the question in the actual html. Fix that, and that may address your issue of overlapping elements.

Comment: "clear: both" on the button container and the following vertical line container did the trick.